# excel to word using VBA

Tags: vba

```
Sub TextFile_Example2()

    Dim Path As String
    Dim FileNumber As Integer
    Dim LR As Integer
    Dim LC As Integer

    Dim k As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

   LR = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   LC = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

   Path = "C:\New folder\textfiles\Hello.txt"
   FileNumber = FreeFile

   Open Path For Output As FileNumber

   For k = 1 To LR

       For i = 1 To LC
           If i <> LC Then
               Print #FileNumber, Cells(i, k),
           Else
              Print #FileNumber, Cells(i, k)
           End If
      Next i

   Next k

   Close FileNumber
 
   Shell "notepad.exe " & Path, vbNormalFocus

End Sub
```

This is the code that convert **excel sheet** to **text file**  But, the problem is that want to print data in desired format.

Excel sheet : [View excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9bU4.png)

and should print the data in text file in desired format

text file :  [View text file][2]

But not able to achieve that any help would be appreciated

Dependent Dropdown :

[click to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9bU4.png)

Comment: why do you have that `If i <> LC` in your inner loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub TextFile_Example7()
Dim sPath As String
Dim FileNumber As Integer
Dim aData As Variant
Dim i As Long, k As Long
    aData = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Value

    sPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\textfiles\"
    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir sPath
    On Error GoTo 0
    sPath = sPath & "Hello_" & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD_HHmmSS") & ".txt"

    FileNumber = FreeFile

    Open sPath For Output As FileNumber

    For i = LBound(aData) + 1 To UBound(aData)
       For k = LBound(aData, 2) To UBound(aData, 2)
            Select Case LCase(aData(1, k))
                Case "first_name"
                    Print #FileNumber, "First Name=" & aData(i, k)
                Case "last_name"
                    Print #FileNumber, "Last Name=" & aData(i, k)
                Case "email_address"
                    Print #FileNumber, "E_mail Address=" & aData(i, k)
                Case "password"
Rem Skip column, nothing to output
                Case Else
                    Print #FileNumber, aData(1, k) & "=" & aData(i, k)
            End Select
        Next k
    Next i

   Close FileNumber
   Shell "notepad.exe " & sPath, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: suppose, if I want to only read  the password column.  but,  should not write to text file
how would this can be achieve

Comment: i want to only read the column lets say last_name column. but should not write, is this possibe ?

Comment: @BhushanAgrawalJSR Of course it is possible! You can program anything you want. Just add `If aData(1, k) <> "password" Then `  before `Print #FileNumber,...`

Comment: Last but not least. This code saves the .txt file once . Is it possible to save with new file always when the code runs.

Comment: @BhushanAgrawalJSR One of the many ways to do this is to include the current date and time in the name of the generated file: `sPath = "C:\New folder\textfiles\Hello_" & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD_HHmmSS") & ".txt"`

Comment: when I run the above code it should create the folder lets say "Textfile",  up or below the Excel file ("Excel1.xlsm") and should save the .txt file into that folder

Comment: Is this Possible ?

Comment: Thanks Sir ! I tested the code and working perfect as per my requests.

Comment: I need One help Sir, I want to read the column heading **first_name**,**last_name**,**email_address**  like wise want to only read and write in the format as **First name**,**Last name** , **E_mail address** I tried If-else, switch case but didn't get the solution.

Comment: How do i replace this strings ? Any suggestion

Comment: Hello sir I have data up to column "J" and skipping the column I have data in column "Z" so how write the Z column data in .txt file. You have used here `For i = LBound(aData) + 1 To UBound(aData)
       For k = LBound(aData, 2) To UBound(aData, 2)` so it does not read and write the data in column Z. Any suggestion Plz !

Comment: Just copy column Z to J before run macro

Comment: I want to read and write data from A to J column and Z column I want not loose the data from column J . I want to read Upto column J and column Z